# Read-only SD cards

Tags: mount, filesystem, sd-card, read-only, card-reader

I've got an IcyBox USB hub/card reader combo in my computer, running Ubuntu 12.10.

It's got an issue with SD cards.  It always mounts them read-only, regardless of the write-lock switch.  This is observed across many SD cards that otherwise work, and crucially occurs for a microSD in an adapter, where the microSD was fine in the microSD slot in the reader.

Anyone got any ideas as to what's going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 15):

It sounds to me to be a permissions issue. I've come across this myself with my Linux Mint 14 (Cinnamon) install, which I believe is based on Ubuntu 12.10.

First thing to do is to check the permissions on the hardware device mounting your card. You'll need to find the device name. To do this run the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Your device will probably be something along the lines of /dev/sdb1, in my case the SD Reader was /dev/mmcblk0p1.

Next you need to get the permissions on this device:

```
sudo ls -l /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Replace "/dev/mmcblk0p1" with your device location.
The output will look something like this:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 1 Feb 3 21:58 /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

This tells us the device is owned by User 'root' and group 'disk'
You need to be a member of group 'disk' to be able to write to the SD card.
You can check which groups your a member of with

```
groups username
```

In my case I was not a member of the 'disk' group, I rectified this with

```
sudo usermod -G disk --append username
```

This adds the group 'disk' to your user's groups, which should allow you to now read & write to the SD card

Comment: "sudo usermod -G disk username" removed my other groups from my account. Adding "--append" will add the group without removing the existing groups.

Comment: --append must be after the group name, like sudo usermod -G disk --append username (else there is an error about group "--append")

Comment: FWIW, `usermod -a -G <group> <username>` is also valid.

Comment: "You need to be a member of group 'disk' to be able to write to the SD card." This is wrong and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Get hold of a PC running windows, download a program called SD Formatting, install and reformat the SD card, making sure the option is set to "ON", it will then be recognised on a Linux machine! without the read only option.

Answer (score 1):

USE:

dosfsck -l -t /dev/sdb

Remove dirty bit (y)
Answer Yes for ALL

Answer (score 1):

In my case Ubuntu auto-mounted the SD Card into a directory it created that didn't have write permissions.

- Once mounted (accessible but read-only), find the mount point: `/media/{username}/{sd-card name}`

  (in my case this was: `/media/andrew/SDCard` - you can find this by right-clicking on the drive, selecting 'Properties' and looking for 'Mounted on', or by typing `mount -l` in a terminal)
- Open a terminal and type the following: `sudo chmod 777 /media/{username}/{sd-card name}`

  e.g. `sudo chmod 777 /media/andrew/SDCard`

The SD card is now writable

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo mount --options remount,rw /dev/sdd
```

Replace `/dev/sdd` with your SDHC drive, you can find it using `fdisk -l`.

Comment: with this command the result is: cannot remount /dev/sdc1 read-write, is write-protected

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem. I noticed other devices were able to write to the SD card.
It turned out to be a bad SD card adapter (the kind with the `ro/rw` switch).