# Problem with SD Card Read-only

Tags: permissions, mount, sd-card, devices

I have problem with a SD card which is Read Only (it's not due to the switch of the card adapter, I've already checked).
I format the SD card with 'Disks' but the card results to be as "Read-only" and I can't change the permission see below.

[image]

I've tried some commands found online but nothing worked for me (I try these solutions: [SD card is read only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698169/sd-card-is-read-only), [MicroSD card is set to Read-only state. How can I write data on it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213889/microsd-card-is-set-to-read-only-state-how-can-i-write-data-on-it) .)
Here's the output of `sudo fdkis -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 29,86 GiB, 32044482560 bytes, 62586880 sectors
Disk model: SD/MMC/MS PRO   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7fa28742

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 62586879 62584832 29,9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
It's not the first time that some devices turn to be as Read-only, but in the past I managed to solve the problem. Now, I don't know what to do. Is there a possibility to never get this problem again?

EDIT 1:
`mount | grep sda` shows the following lines:

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/sda1 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro,x-gvfs-show)
```

EDIT 2:
I've tried to do `sudo nautilus` and then to change owne, group, others and actions of all them, but those changes are not saved since it said "you don't have the permissions necessary to...".

EDIT 3
I've also tried to format the sd card, but after that there's still the same problem.

EDIT 4
Incredibly, in Windows it works perfectly.

EDIT 5
The output of `sudo umount /dev/sda1` and `sudo dosfsck -a /dev/sda1` is:

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/sda1: 15 files, 45742/1954819 clusters
```

Comment: Keep in mind that SD cards die eventually and this is one of the signs that it's dead or dying

Comment: I usually get clues from messages when it is mounted (esp. given the command that mounts it). If you use GUI tools to `mount`, you'll need to view those messages in logs (if card not dead/dying, I'd expect it's an unclear file-system)

Comment: The card is not dead because it worked until one hour ago...

Comment: What size SD card is it? The 1st generation SD cards have a read-only switch on the side.

Comment: Could you update with ```mount | grep sda```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what happens when you try to create a file or move a file to the volume?  Your screenshot shows nothing out of place because root owns the *mount point* (`/dev/sdx#`)... This does not indicate that the SD card is read only.

Comment: @Frobozz I've updated with what you told me.

Comment: @Nmath I cannot paste any file in the SD Card with right click. Also I cannot drag any file into the SD Card.

Comment: @Raffles I've already turned that switch on

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky make it work again. But the card might also be damaged 'beyond repair'.

Comment: @sudodus that link doesn't solve the problem unofrtunately. I'm sure that the sd card life is not finished (two days ago I delete and move some files on it, but after removing it unsafely it does not work anymore)

Comment: Put it into a Windows computer. Windows will prompt you to repair the SD card if it is readable but damaged.

Comment: @Raffles I've done what you says. After that, the SD card works fine on Windows but not in Ubuntu...

Comment: Try `sudo umount  /dev/sda1` and then `sudo dosfsck -a /dev/sda1` Paste the result in your post. This could be a bug.

Comment: @Raffles done it

Comment: Does it do the same thing with other SD cards? It would be useful to know if any other users are experiencing the same problem?

Comment: @Raffles  I will try with another SDASAP. What's seems strange is that initially the card worked also on Ubuntu. After an unsafely eject, it does not work properly anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113350/discussion-between-raffles-and-mcp).

Answer (score 2):

*The following answer was submitted by the question's author who [posted the answer as part of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1276558/7):*

---

SOLUTION: I wipe the whole device with mkusb and then format the sd card in order to create a FAT partition. Now it works fine: I can paste and delete everything on it.