# Why are some mass storeage devices read only?

Tags: permissions

I have a card reader in my laptop. Today I needed to copy some files to the SD card.

Unfortunately, Ubuntu said it's read only. It wouldn't let me set permissions for the SD card in nautilus either.

It copies files to USB sticks and phones but not to the SD.

How do I fix this?

Comment: SD cards usually have a hardware switch to toggle between read-only and read-write, are you sure it's not flipped to read-only?

Comment: No, it's unlocked. I think it has something to do with permissions. How do I change those for a volume? When i try to do any operations on it it says "Error while copying to “16 GB Volume”. The destination is read-only."

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/251047/380067

Comment: This worked, after a reboot though. Anyway why would such thing happen?

Comment: To be honest, what the rationale behind that would be is not occuring to me right now. Well at least it was easilty fixable. I'm voting to close as a duplicate of that question then.